# add round of 30 minutes to current time in objective c

Tags: objective-c

i want to add round of 30 minutes 4 hours difference in current time in objective c.

Ex: 11.30 - 16.00

11.00 - 15.30 11.45 to 15.30

How can i do this?

Comment: This is not clear. Can you put more details?

Comment: time calculated add to 4 hours and 30 minutes  from current time. if current time 11.11 means it show 15.30 11.30 means 16.00 (24 hours format)

Comment: What are you trying to ask?

Comment: Need help to show the time intervals for every 30 mins, suppose the current time is 11:45 am then time should me 15.30

Comment: help me anyone plZ

Comment: how to convert 2017-02-10 10:30:00 +0000 to 16.30 i convert many ways but not converting properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addition of 4 hours and 30 minutes can be done with `NSCalendar`'s [`-dateByAddingComponents:toDate:options:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscalendar/1409577-datebyaddingcomponents?language=objc), and the rounding can be done with [`-nextDateAfterDate:matchingUnit:value:options:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscalendar/1417170-nextdateafterdate?language=objc):

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

// This assumes you want to use the Gregorian calendar.
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];

// Add 4 hours and 30 minutes
NSDateComponents *fourAndAHalfHours = [NSDateComponents new];
fourAndAHalfHours.hour = 4;
fourAndAHalfHours.minute = 30;
NSDate *future = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:fourAndAHalfHours toDate:now options:NSCalendarMatchNextTimePreservingSmallerUnits];

// Now we want to round to next 30 minutes. If we're past the 30 minute mark, round to 0.
// Otherwise, round to 30.
NSInteger minutes = [calendar component:NSCalendarUnitMinute fromDate:future];
NSInteger roundTo = minutes >= 30 ? 0 : 30;

NSDate *rounded = [calendar nextDateAfterDate:future matchingUnit:NSCalendarUnitMinute value:roundTo options:NSCalendarMatchStrictly];
```

Note that `NSCalendarMatchStrictly` here will, across daylight savings time changes, get you the next available hour after the change. If you are looking for different behavior, also look at [`NSCalendarMatchNextTimePreservingSmallerUnits`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscalendaroptions/nscalendarmatchnexttimepreservingsmallerunits?language=objc) and [`NSCalendarMatchNextTime`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscalendaroptions/nscalendarmatchnexttime?language=objc).

Comment: can u tell me how to change this NSDate *rounded = [calendar nextDateAfterDate:future matchingUnit:NSCalendarUnitMinute value:roundTo options:NSCalendarMatchStrictly]; to 24 hour format time

Comment: @evelinprissy You can use an [`NSDateFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdateformatter) to take a date and convert it to a string in any format that you need, including 24 hour time.

Comment: NSDateFormatter *df =[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
    NSString *obj=[df stringFromDate:rounded];
    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *obj1=[df dateFromString:obj];
    [df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
    NSString *obj3=[df stringFromDate:obj1];
i used this but is not converting properly

Comment: how to convert 2017-02-10 10:30:00 +0000 to 16.30 i convert many ways but not converting properly – evelin prissy just now   edit

Comment: @evelinprissy Why go from a date to a string to a date to a string? Just go to a string directly: `[df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"]; NSString *formatted = [df stringFromDate:rounded];`

Comment: Also, keep in mind that the default time zone on the date formatter is GMT. That will show the wrong time if the user is not in GMT, so use the user's time zone if relevant.

Comment: Don't add seconds, add date components.

Comment: @Willeke Sure, you can do that too. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 NSDate *dt = [NSDate date];
 NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
 NSDateComponents *comps = [cal components:NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond fromDate:dt];
 comps.hour = 4;
 if(comps.minute >= 30)
      comps.minute = -(comps.minute-30);
 else
      comps.minute = -comps.minute;
 comps.second = -comps.second;
 NSDate *newDate = [cal dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:dt options:0];
```